# How to compress a large file to many smaller zip files with defined size?

Tags: linux, gzip, zip

I have a very large file, e.g. 100GB, and I want to compress it to many smaller zip file, with each file cannot larger than 1GB, what would be the most suitable commands to do it?

remark: I want to optimize the smaller number of files created

**Update**: I want each file can be decompressed independently

Comment: try http://www.7-zip.org/ it gives better compression usually but takes lot of time and I use its GUI (linux) to split files to smaller sizes.

Answer (score 2):

Just make one large zip file and then use the linux [`split`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split) command to break it up into smaller pieces. `cat` can be used, then, to re-assemble them into a large file.

If you wanted to break up a file into 1GB chunks, the split command would be something like:

```
$ split -b 1073741824 myfile.zip myfile-split-
```

To re-assemble:

```
$ cat myfile-split-* > myfile.zip
```

Your compression ratio would drastically decrease if you actually went to multiple zip files.

I would highly recommend making sure you take an md5sum of the file before the split and then making sure the md5 matches after re-assembly.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question, I want each file can be decompressed independently

Comment: You realize that is going to *kill* your compression ratio, right?

Comment: Yes, but the size limit of 1GB is a hard limit we need to follow

Comment: Why do you need each file to be able to be decompressed independently? That seems like an odd requirement.

Comment: Because this is our workflow, a program read from a compressed file and do the job, the file limit is 1GB compressed